# The following assertion was thrown while resolving an image: Unable to load asset: AssetManifest.json

Tags: flutter, testing, widget, assets

So, I made a [pub.dev flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/arculus_auth_widgets) which uses an image asset.

```dart
class GoogleIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isEnabled;

  const GoogleIcon({
    Key key = const Key('google-icon'),
    this.isEnabled = true,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: isEnabled ? 1 : 0.5,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/google.png',
        key: Key('google-icon-image'),
        package: 'arculus_auth_widgets',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In that library, each of the widget tests run as expected. But when I tried to use the widget in the test of my other package (which depends on it) like this:

```dart
  testWidgets('should show buttons at the bottom', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: ArculusOnboardingBody(
            buttons: [
              ArculusGoogleButton(label: 'Continue with Google'), // This widget contains GoogleIcon in it
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
  });
```

It failed with

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE
> ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> assertion was thrown while resolving an image: Unable to load asset:
> AssetManifest.json
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7) 
> #1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:68:33)
> #2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:167:18)
> #3      CachingAssetBundle.loadStructuredData (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:188:5)
> #4      AssetImage.obtainKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart:176:18)
> #5      ScrollAwareImageProvider.obtainKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:115:74)
> #6      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey. (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:455:15)
> #10     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:452:16)
> #11     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:330:5)
> #12     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1156:16)
> #13     _ImageState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1109:5)
> #14     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4786:12)
> #15     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5) ...     Normal
> element mounting (16 frames)
> #31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
> #32     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6236:32) ...     Normal
> element mounting (223 frames)
> #255    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
> #256    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6236:32) ...     Normal
> element mounting (37 frames)
> #293    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
> #294    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6236:32) ...     Normal
> element mounting (202 frames)
> #496    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
> #497    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6236:32) ...     Normal
> element mounting (267 frames)
> #764    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
> #765    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3324:20)
> #766    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1252:16)
> #767    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1230:5)
> #768    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1244:7)
> #769    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
> #770    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2730:33)
> #771    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1088:18)
> #772    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:302:5)
> #773    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
> #774    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1055:9)
> #775    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump. (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:961:9)
> #778    TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:72:41)
> #779    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:948:27)
> #780    WidgetTester.pumpWidget. (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:524:22)
> #783    TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:72:41)
> #784    WidgetTester.pumpWidget (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:521:27)
> #785    main. (file:///Users/moseskarunia/Projects/arculus/test/src/widgets/arculus_onboarding_body_test.dart:67:18)
> #786    main. (file:///Users/moseskarunia/Projects/arculus/test/src/widgets/arculus_onboarding_body_test.dart:66:52)
> #787    testWidgets.. (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:146:29)
> #798    FakeAsync.flushMicrotasks (package:fake_async/fake_async.dart:193:32)
> #799    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest. (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1189:17)
> #800    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest. (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1177:35) (elided 32 frames from
> dart:async and package:stack_trace)
>
> Image provider: ScrollAwareImageProvider() Image
> configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#2377c(),
> devicePixelRatio: 3.0,   locale: en_US, textDirection:
> TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> Test failed. See exception logs above. The test description was:
> should show buttons at the bottom
>
> ✖ should show buttons at the bottom Exited (1)

Do you know where did I do it wrong? It behaves correctly in the actual run though (outside of the test)

Thanks.

This is my `flutter doctor -v`

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64,
> locale en-ID)
> • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/moseskarunia/Development/flutter
> • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (5 days ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
> • Engine revision 2f0af37152
> • Dart version 2.10.5
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 29.0.2)
> • Android SDK at /Users/moseskarunia/Development/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
> • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/moseskarunia/Development/Android/sdk
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
> • CocoaPods version 1.10.1
>
> [!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
> ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
> • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
> • Flutter extension version 3.18.1
>
> [!] Connected device
> ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Comment: How do you communicate with `AssetManifest.json` asset?

Comment: @fartem well I didn't. I don't even know why the error is about AssetManifest.json though.

Comment: Can you search it in the project?

Comment: @fartem i wasn't able to find any. Do you have any experience dealing with it? Maybe a direction would be great as well. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38510) is the similar issue on GitHub, try to find solution in it.

Comment: @fartem btw this happens just in tests. The actual code run fine.